# UIImagePickerController inside popoverview causing error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am trying to create a UIPopoverView that contains a UIImagePickerController for taking photos only. I have attempted to create something like this when I press a button on my toolbar. The method looks like this.

```
- (void) cameraButtonSelected
{
    // create picker
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    // create popover
    UIPopoverController *popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
    [popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 350) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

the issue being this procduces the following error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController dealloc] reached while popover is still visible.'
```

I am not sure exactly what this means so was hoping I could get some help on the matter.

Comment: other possibility is , Check if it has already invoked.

Answer (score 1):

`UIPopoverController` should always be held in an instance variable.

Please refer this [UIPopovercontroller dealloc reached while popover is still visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895071/uipopovercontroller-dealloc-reached-while-popover-is-still-visible)

Answer (score 1):

Try to create `UIPopoverController` as public, I mean declare it in **.h** file and then use it.

Such like

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController * popOver;
```

And then use it in **.m** file, such like....

```
.
.
.
.
self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 350) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: It is not necessary to be strong, nor in .h

Comment: if not declare in .h then hows you held it in an instance variable?

Comment: There are lots of ways for solve this issue .. but if anything is wrong in my code then you can correct me THanks mate :)

Comment: No it is a correct answer +1, but just to take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `UIPopover` as a property.

Like:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popOver;
```

Use it like:

```
self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
[self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(10, 30, 200, 350) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: @null: that's necessary, If you are declaring it as a property. If you are declaring it as a variable, then no issue.